# What is the expected damage per round on each level?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, balance

I'm trying to make a homebrew star wars setting using the 5e rules, in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* are guidelines for futuristic weapons, but the damage of those weapons looks like the perfect ingredient for a massive unbalance issue.

So I'm wondering, Are there tables or charts with the expected DPR/Level of the PC's?

Comment: This is likely either far too broad, as a list of expected DPR/level would be dependant on a number of different variables, largely of which would be race/class and a list of DPR/level for each race/class combination would be way too long for the stack format, or off topic as a shopping question if you're asking *where* to find such tables/charts, since I'm fairly certain they would have to come from a third party.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I'm pretty sure that this is assuming the existence of a single DPR number per level number that the designers designed towards, and not asking the far broader question of what the expected DPR/level per race/class combo is.

Comment: Um just curious but why dont you use the actual Age of Rebellion, Force and Destiny stuff for the Star wars rpg Green Ronin put out?

Comment: My group doesn't like it, they want to "update" the old d20 star wars.

Comment: The answer to this question would probably be: How deadly would you want your weapons to be? If you reuse the damage of the range weapons in the 5e rule book you would quite nicely end with battles that are as dangerous as in DnD. If you increase damage it would be quire more dangerous. This is no problem if you and your player are OK with a Blaster hit being deadly. But might make things more difficult to manage.